# How to create private repository in Github using PyGithub

Tags: python, github, automation, webautomation, pygithub

I figured out how to create repository on Github using PyGIthub by this method:

```
import sys
from github import Github

g = Github('AryanshMahato', 'GITHUB_PASSWORD')

user = g.get_user()
repo = user.create_repo(folderName)
```

But in this case PyGithub creates a public repository.

How can I create a private repository using PyGithub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official docs: [Organization.create_repo](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Organization.html#github.Organization.Organization.create_repo)

You can set `private` parameter to `True`

```
repo = user.create_repo(folderName, private=True)
```